# imwrite sequence of images in a folder in opencv

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opencv

Using VS 2010 in C++ and tried to put this in a for loop

```
String filename = "cropped_" + (ct+1);
imwrite(filename + ".jpg", img_cropped);
```

These are the filenames that came out:

```
ropped_.jpg
opped_.jpg
pped_.jpg
```

How do I do it? And how do I put them in a folder in the same directory as my source code?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `std::stringstream` to build sequential file names:

First include the `sstream` header from the C++ standard library.

```
#include<sstream>

using namespace std;
```

Then inside your code, you can do the following:

```
stringstream ss;

string name = "cropped_";
string type = ".jpg";

ss<<name<<(ct + 1)<<type;

string filename = ss.str();
ss.str("");

imwrite(filename, img_cropped);
```

To create new folder, you can use windows' command `mkdir` in the `system` function from `stdlib.h`:

```
 string folderName = "cropped";
 string folderCreateCommand = "mkdir " + folderName;

 system(folderCreateCommand.c_str());

 ss<<folderName<<"/"<<name<<(ct + 1)<<type;

 string fullPath = ss.str();
 ss.str("");

 imwrite(fullPath, img_cropped);
```

Comment: It worked! Thanks! This one's shorted than the one I came up with. 

Is it possible to put the images in a folder automatically?

Comment: Well.. to create a new folder automatically, you would have to add some additional code to create a directory using the [`CreateDirectory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363855(v=vs.85).aspx) function from `windows.h`

Comment: I have a question. I used mkdir("cropped") to make a cropped folder an that did it. However, idk how to put the images inside it. Do you know how?

Comment: I can't thank you enough! If only I can double check your answer !

Answer (score 3):

```
    for (int ct = 0; ct < img_SIZE ; ct++){
    char filename[100];
    char f_id[3];       //store int to char*
    strcpy(filename, "cropped_"); 
    itoa(ct, f_id, 10);
    strcat(filename, f_id);
    strcat(filename, ".jpg");

    imwrite(filename, img_cropped); }
```

By the way, here's a longer version of @sgar91's answer

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
char file_name[100];
sprintf(file_name, "cropped%d.jpg", ct + 1);
imwrite(file_name, img_cropped);
```

They should just go in the directory where you run your code, otherwise, you'll have to manually specify like this:

```
sprintf(file_name, "C:\path\to\source\code\cropped%d.jpg", ct + 1);
```

Comment: Hi thanks but it says conversion of cv::String to char* does not exist.

As for the folder, do you have any idea to do it? To automatically create a folder and put the images in it?

Comment: `sprintf` takes destination argument of type `char*`. It expects an already allocated large enough `char` array, not an `std::string`. To use `sprintf`, `file_name` should be like `char file_name[256]`.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is the first result for a google search I will add my answer using std::filesystem (C++17)

```
std::filesystem::path root = std::filesystem::current_path();
std::filesystem::create_directories(root / "my_images");

for (int num_image = 0; num_image < 10; num_image++){

    // Perform some operations....
    cv::Mat im_out;
    std::stringstream filename;
    filename << "my_images"<< "/" << "image" << num_image << ".bmp";
    cv::imwrite(filename.str(), im_out);
}
```