# video playing in opencv: no error no output

Tags: c++, opencv

I have written a program to display a stored video file using `opencv`. I attached the code below. I am not getting any errors while building it but no output is displayed.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
              if (argc <= 1)
              {
                      printf("Usage: %s video\n", argv[0]);
                      return -1;
              }


              VideoCapture capture(argv[1]);
              namedWindow("display",cv::WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

              capture.set(cv::CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 640);
              capture.set(cv::CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 480); 


              if(!capture.isOpened())
              {

                              printf("Failed to open the video\n");
                              return -1;
               }

               int i;

               for(i=0;i<390;i++)
               {
                          Mat frame;


                          capture >> frame; // get a new frame from camera

                          cout << "frame =" << endl << " " <<  frame << endl << endl; 
                          imshow("display",frame);
                }

                }
```

I included the `cout` line at the end to check if the frame is getting any value or not. So a got a number of values in a matrix, but the video window is not appearing.

Answer (score 2):

You have to add a very small delay after `imshow` by using `waitKey`.

```
imshow("display",frame);
waitKey(10); //Wait 10 milliseconds before showing next frame.
```

Comment: thanks for the answer the window is being displayed now.. is ter any way to store each frame as an image. i used imwrite, but only the last frame was stored.

Comment: are you using the same filename for each imwrite?

Comment: @wireless_lab... Check my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14620111/1231073). This may help.